# There are some benefits to have/having an experience

Tags: difference, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

Can you help me with this rule?

I have no idea about its name (maybe gerund?).

But Word offers me to change *"have"* to *"having"*.

Why should (or shouldn't) I do it here?:

- There are some benefits to ***have / (having)*** an experience in a part-time job before starting working full time.

Comment: Whole sentence please! Simple rule 'to' + verb is called infinitive and '-ing' form of the same verb is called gerund (a verb that functions the same as a noun). The sentence would be okay if you replace 'to' with 'of' while adding 'having' instead of 'have'. But sometimes it sounds weird if you replace an infinitive with the gerund form; depends from context-to-context.

Comment: I've change the sentence. Now it's the same as it was when the Word advise me to change "have" to "having".

Comment: What's the most appropriate variant in this way? Whether "to have" or "to having" or "of having"...

Comment: Microsoft Word can be wrong sometimes (personal experience). It should be proper the way it is, i.e. infinitive form: _There are some benefits to have an experience in a part-time job before starting working full time_. Otherwise like I suggested in my previous comment: _There are some benefits of having an experience in a part-time job before starting working full time._ Personally speaking the gerund form sounds better.

Comment: I must point that some people would suggest not to use two gerunds one after the other. _before starting working..._ You can consider writing it as: _before starting (to) work full time._